# Scrapy: parse a div from a list of divs

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to parse a website. The HTML code of which is:

```
<li class="listclass">
    <div class="divclass"> Some text </div>
    <div> "Some text" </div>
</li>
```

I want to get the text present in the second `div`.

How do I parse it so as to get the required text?

What I have currently is:

```
response.xpath('//li[@class="listclass"]/div/text()').extract()
```

The problem is that here the text corresponding to both the `divs` is being selected. I just need the contents of the second div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have lot of div's and you need to avoid particular div mean you can use this.

```
response.xpath('//li[@class=listclass"]/div[not(contains(@class,"divclass"))]/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//li[@class="listclass"]/div[2]/text()
```